# PostgreSQL identity in JPA single table hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm seeing strange behaviour when using PostgreSQL in a Hibernate/JPA environment with a single table inheritance hierarchy.

Firstly my environment:

- PostgreSQL 8.3
- Spring 2.5.6SEC01
- Hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA (installed from Glassfish update tool)
- Hibernate-distribution 3.3.1.GA (installed from Glassfish update tool)
- Glassfish V2
- Mac OS X 10.5.x

I'm having an issue when using a `GenerationType` of `IDENTITY` with a single table inheritance hierarchy.

Here are my two entities:

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="generation", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("Parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Child")
public class Child extends Parent {
    private String babyName;

    /**
     * @return the babyName
     */
    public String getBabyName() {
        return babyName;
    }

    /**
     * @param babyName the babyName to set
     */
    public void setBabyName(String babyName) {
        this.babyName = babyName;
    }
}
```

**DDL**

```
create table Parent (generation varchar(31) not null
                    ,id  bigserial not null
                    ,babyName varchar(255)
                    ,primary key (id)
                    );
```

If I try to insert a new Parent I get an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : Parent
```

I turned up the logging to TRACE and this is the output:

```
TRACE TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@485e0366] for key [com.sun.enterprise.util.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper@a6e312b] to thread [httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-0]
Hibernate: insert into Parent (generation) values ('Parent')
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003
Bad value for type long : Parent
TRACE TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [com.xxx.yyy.service.MoveService.saveHuman] after exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [com.xxx.yyy.temp.Parent]
TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [com.xxx.yyy.temp.Parent]
```

If I change the discriminator value to be something that parses as a long e.g. `123` the insert succeeds. However Hibernate seems to think this discriminator value is the id. So the following code:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
service.saveHuman(p);

add(new Label("p", "p id is" + p.getId()));
```

Shows the id as `123` rather than the primary key value which is 1.

If I change the generation type to `AUTO` a single sequence is created and the insert seems to work ok. If I change it to `SEQUENCE` and declare the sequence with a class-level annotation again it works. However according to the documentation I have read PostgreSQL supports both generation types.

I also tried the exact same code and switched out the database with MySQL 5.0.51b. This seems to function fine.

So is this a bug in my code, the dialect, Hibernate, or the PostgreSQL JDBC driver? Any ideas how I can narrow down the problem? Anyone able to re-produce this issue as I have tried to search and haven't seen this exact problem yet.

**Note:** I've also asked the question on the [Hibernate Forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=999196). Naturally I will feedback any responses to both sites.

Comment: Which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: It's postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar. That's a good point - I'll try another version to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Matt Solnit Just tried postgresql-8.3-605.jdbc4 and it works ok! Thanks very much. If you want to write this up as an answer I'll assign it to you.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I added a "regular" answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just "porting" this solution from the comments above... use version 8.3 of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver :-).