# bad value for type long: - Postgresql, Hibernate, Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, blob

I wanna store an entity(a String + an image) in PostgresQL using Spring MVC and Hibernate
Here is my table. The image is supposed to be the type of oid.

```
CREATE TABLE document
(
  name character varying(200),
  id serial NOT NULL,
  content oid,   // that should be the image
  CONSTRAINT document_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Here is the entity that I want to store.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "document")
    public class Document {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="content")
            private Blob content;  //this is the image
//getters- setters
```

You can see the variable "name" is a String, not Long. Still when I submit the form with a value which is not numeric it throws  `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : x`

here is the form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save.html" commandName="document" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="error"/>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="content">Document</form:label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Document"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

If I enter a numeric value and submit it, OK. But any non-numeric value triggers the above mentioned exception...I read that it might be caused by that I do not use OID properly but I do not know what should I do to eliminate this exception. Actually I do not understand the name of the excpetion either. It says "bad value for type **long**" . but who wants type long? **the variable "name" is type String!!!!**

Finally, here is the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("document") Document document, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    try {
        Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());
        document.setContent(blob);
        documentDao.save(document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "redirect:/index.html";
}
```

Any advice is appriciated.

Comment: You may want to try annotating your Blob declaration with the hibernate @Lob annotation. Also, it may help to turn on hibernate's query output so you can see the sql that is being generated and see if it gives you a hint as to what is being sent to the database.

Comment: An OID can't hold a BLOB. ["The oid type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte integer."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-oid.html). I suppose that's where the error comes from.

Comment: @madth3 `oid` is used to hold a reference to a large object in the `pg_largeobject` table.

Comment: Of course, sorry for that. Did you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1333596/422353)? What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when I created the table the column "name" happened to be the first. That's not good.
Id must be the first column. If I change the order of columns it works fine...

Comment: @Regenbogenfisch - how to change the order or column ?? I am also facing this problem. I have tried it in pgAdmin III but can't, so will you help me ?

Comment: simply drop table and recreate it.

Answer (score 96):

I had a similiar problem but it was not related to the order of ID field in the database.

After some searching I found [this](http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/299/string-lobs-on-postgresql-with-hibernate-36.html) pointing to the fact that Lobs in Hibernate are treated as OIDs unless otherwise specified.

That means Hibernate will try put a Lob into a Long a hence produce that exception **PSQLException: Bad value for type long**

The way to specify that the Lob is a to be treated as text is by annotating the field

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
```

Comment: You could as well use `@Column(columnDefinition = "text")` instead of lob+type.

Comment: Using `columnDefinition` didn't worked for me. But using `@Type` did.

Comment: I confirmed the problem with Hibernate 3.6.8 and PostgreSQL 9.4. 
After apply the Tšeliso Molukanele's solution it worked fine.

Comment: It saved my day! The strange thing about the error I was getting is that the field pointed in the logs was not the TEXT one.

Answer (score 6):

At first I tried to set

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
```

instead of @Lob annotation, as already mentioned here. It worked for me on PostgreSQL, but with error
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [htmlText] in table [Question]; found [clob (Types#CLOB)], but expecting [text (Types#VARCHAR)]

in my unit tests (on HSQLDB).

Then it tried

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "clob")
```

And it works well on both PostgreSQL and HSQLDB!

Answer (score 2):

Problem exist on Postgres and Hibernate. Column `text` can't be mapped to String.
You need to add : **@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.TextType")**

Example :

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
@Column
private String contentJson;
```

If column contains binary type, use :
**@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")**

Solution founded on page : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5995

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Column` and columnDefinition to stay compliant with the JPA spec

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB")
```

or Hibernate annotation `@Type` with JPA @Lob annotation if its okay for you to use Hibernate annotations

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced smiler error and the reason was that I was having some characters other than integer in integer data type filed

e.g.- ,111 and 144- etc