# Can not set [B field fr.mypackage.MyClass.data to java.lang.String

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, bytea

I am struggling with this problem :

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by
> reflection setter of fr.mypackage.MyClass.data
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set [B field
> fr.mypackage.MyClass.data to java.lang.String

The problem above is about MyClass which is an entity with two attributes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TG_CLASS")
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    @Column(name = "DATA")
    private byte[] data;

...

}
```

It looks pretty simple, the only tricky thing is the column DATA which is a bytea (I am working in PostgreSQL), and that the problem comes from Hibernate struggling with converting bytea to String. How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with `BYTEA` column and your entity has a `byte[]`, you shouldn't be using `org.hibernate.type.TextType`. It's for c(haracter)lobs, you're working with bytes not characters.

Additionally there are many ways to convert bytes to characters and vice versa, these are called encodings. I wouldn't trust silent conversions where I don't know which encoding is being used. You could end up with corrupt data without realizing it.

Comment: Indeed, the problem came from org.hibernate.type.TextType. I changed it to org.hibernate.type.BinaryType and it works pretty well now ! Thank you !

Comment: Do you need the annotation at all? What type is inferred if you leave it out completely?

Comment: Without any annotation, I have an exception org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: bad value for type long

Comment: Ah alright, so it's this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647755/bad-value-for-type-long-postgresql-hibernate-spring

Comment: Exactly, that's how I came up trying @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"), thank you !