# How to use CLOB with Hibernate and both Postgres and H2

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm trying to store a long text file into the DBMS. Here is my table definition :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")
public class Foo {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7111245814238004034L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "content", length = 100_000)
    private String content;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

And here is my liquibase changeset :

```
    <createTable tableName="foos">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" />
        <column name="content" type="clob" />
    </createTable>
```

This work fine with H2 but with Postgres, when I try load a Foo, I get :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : <content>
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:2876)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2083)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getClob(PgResultSet.java:452)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getClob(PgResultSet.java:439)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getClob(DelegatingResultSet.java:675)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getClob(DelegatingResultSet.java:675)
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
```

(saving a Foo to the database works though).

If I try to add another annotation to  `content` :

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
```

This works fine with Postgres (prod environnement) but not with H2 (test env) :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [content] in table [public.war_contexts]; found [clob (Types#CLOB)], but expecting [varchar(2147483647) (Types#LONGVARCHAR)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 81 more
```

Any idea on how to solve the issue on both DBMS (and bonus points if it works with MariaDB or Oracle)

EDIT:

tried those conneciton settings

```
jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

But it's not helping

Comment: Actually there is no standard `CLOB` data type in PostgreSQL. H2 supports this data type, but `TEXT` in H2 is also mapped to `CLOB`. Hibernate schema validation complains too often about different, but still compatible data types; you need to disable it if you really want to use different databases, usually it's a bad idea to use different database systems for tests and production.

Comment: What about testing? When I run my tests I get the exact same error

Comment: I had the same problem with Postgres and H2. Using `@Column(columnDefinition = "clob")` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540749/4545255) solved it.

Answer (score 8):

Annotate your field with `@Column(columnDefinition = "text")` as follows:

```java
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String content;
```

Then make sure that your column type is equal to the SQL `text` type!

My Spring datasource config looks as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password: sa
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I tested it with Hibernate 5 and it works both with Postgres and H2.

Comment: in my case (hibernate 6.2.5), having `@Lob @Column(columnDefinition = "text") String message;` produces  `Bad value for type long : hello_world` when querying the table. Without the `columnDefinition`, hibernate uses `oid` type for the column. With `columnDefinition`, it uses `text`, but still expects to read `oid`.

Comment: actually it was hibernate 5.6.15. I also forgot to mention my database is PostgreSQL 11

Comment: @trogper I added that I only tested it with Hibernate 5!