# Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I am using PostgreSQL 13 as the backend database server, the MyBatis used to be the ORM framework, today I am facing a problem like this:

```
[20:34:19:196] [ERROR] - com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.pay.alipay.AlipayNotificationController.handleNotification(AlipayNotificationController.java:85) - handle notification failed
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column #1 from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : vOghoo10L9
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:96) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar!/:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar!/:2.0.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.insert(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:272) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar!/:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.insertSelective(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.user.UserSubService.insertUserSub(UserSubService.java:57) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.product.sub.IapProductSubHandler.handleNonSubScribe(IapProductSubHandler.java:87) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.product.sub.IapProductSubHandler.handleSubByType(IapProductSubHandler.java:62) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.product.sub.IapProductSubHandler.productPaySuccess(IapProductSubHandler.java:51) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.pay.alipay.AlipayNotificationController.handleNotificationImpl(AlipayNotificationController.java:117) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.pay.alipay.AlipayNotificationController.handleNotification(AlipayNotificationController.java:83) [classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.pay.alipay.AlipayNotificationController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a911fc6b.invoke(<generated>) [classes!/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) [spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) [spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123) [spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) [spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) [spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.pay.alipay.AlipayNotificationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99f5c6c.handleNotification(<generated>) [classes!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67) [spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142) [spring-session-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) [spring-session-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
```

the string value `vOghoo10L9` was the app id, in the database the app id datatype is varchar. This is the table which `insertUserSub` saved data to:

```
-- public.user_sub definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.user_sub;

CREATE TABLE public.user_sub (
    app_id varchar NOT NULL,
    product_id int4 NOT NULL,
    iap_product_id varchar NOT NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_time int8 NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NOT NULL,
    sub_start_time int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    sub_end_time int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    enabled int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    order_id varchar NOT NULL,
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT user_sub_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_sub_un UNIQUE (order_id)
);
```

where is the problem? waht should I to to fixed it? The insert mapper look like this:

```
<insert id="insertSelective" keyProperty="id" parameterType="com.dolphin.soa.post.model.entity.UserSub" useGeneratedKeys="true">
<!--
  WARNING - @mbggenerated
  This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
-->
insert into user_sub
<trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
  <if test="appId != null">
    app_id,
  </if>
  <if test="productId != null">
    product_id,
  </if>
  <if test="iapProductId != null">
    iap_product_id,
  </if>
  <if test="createdTime != null">
    created_time,
  </if>
  <if test="updatedTime != null">
    updated_time,
  </if>
  <if test="userId != null">
    user_id,
  </if>
  <if test="subStartTime != null">
    sub_start_time,
  </if>
  <if test="subEndTime != null">
    sub_end_time,
  </if>
  <if test="enabled != null">
    enabled,
  </if>
  <if test="orderId != null">
    order_id,
  </if>
</trim>
<trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
  <if test="appId != null">
    #{appId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
  </if>
  <if test="productId != null">
    #{productId,jdbcType=INTEGER},
  </if>
  <if test="iapProductId != null">
    #{iapProductId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
  </if>
  <if test="createdTime != null">
    #{createdTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
  </if>
  <if test="updatedTime != null">
    #{updatedTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
  </if>
  <if test="userId != null">
    #{userId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
  </if>
  <if test="subStartTime != null">
    #{subStartTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
  </if>
  <if test="subEndTime != null">
    #{subEndTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
  </if>
  <if test="enabled != null">
    #{enabled,jdbcType=SMALLINT},
  </if>
  <if test="orderId != null">
    #{orderId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
  </if>
</trim>
```

Comment: It seems that MyBatis think that in Java `app_id` is of type `Long` (wrong) instead of `String` (correct). Are you selecting, inserting, deleting, or updating the table?

Comment: when Insert record into the table shows this error, seems the mybatis think the first column is id.

Comment: What java type are you defining for the `app_id` column?

Comment: I defined the appid data type to varchar

Comment: That's the JDBC type. In Java, what's the type of the Java property in the Java class?

Comment: private String appId;

Comment: Please show your MyBatis mappings. In [Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12647755/4808122) solved either with reordering of columns or with a `@Lob` annotation.

Comment: @Dolphin The error occurs when setting the generated key to `id` property of `UserSub`. When `keyColumn` is not specified, PostgreSQL returns all columns of the inserted row and the first column of the result set (probably) is `app_id`. The solution is to add `keyColumn="id"` to `<insert>`.